# What is this math font?

Tags: fonts

[image]

I designated "D" on the image.

What is this math font called?

.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just sans-serif. Try `\mathsf{D}`?

Comment: Thanks! Then how about to make it bold? I tried \mathbf{\mathsf{D}} , but it does not works.

Comment: Computer Modern does not have a bold sans-serif face, you will have to select a font that does have such a face

Comment: Also unlike text font commands `\mathxx` fonts do not combine so you would need to declare a new math alphabet for bold sans not use `\mathbf{\mathsf`

Answer (score 2):

You can either define your own math alphabet (here `\mathbfsf`) for bold sans-serif

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{OT1}{cmss}{bx}{n}
\begin{document}

$\mathsf{D}$ $\mathbfsf{D}$

\end{document}
```

or you can use the `bm` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

$\mathsf{D}$ $\bm{\mathsf{D}}$

\end{document}
```

The output is in both cases

[image]